# Trouble synchronizing threads with Apache Mina

Tags: java, networking, apache-mina

I'm using Apache Mina 1.1.7 and Java 1.6. The server sends a sequence of three messages to the client in loop. Sometimes two sets of messages overlap. For example, I am expecting:

```
++ recv: MSGHEAD 
++ recv: message body 1
++ recv: .

++ recv: MSGHEAD 
++ recv: message body 2
++ recv: .
```

but I get this instead:

```
++ recv: MSGHEAD
++ recv: MSGHEAD 
++ recv: message body 1
++ recv: .
++ recv: message body 2
++ recv: .
```

Here is my server configuration:

```
    SocketAcceptor acceptor = new SocketAcceptor();
    SocketAcceptorConfig config = new SocketAcceptorConfig();
    config.setThreadModel(ThreadModel.MANUAL);
    if (true) {
        SSLContextFactory factory = new SSLContextFactory();
        config.getFilterChain().addLast("sslFilter", new SSLFilter(factory.getInstance(true)));
    }

    System.out.println(config.getFilterChain().toString());
    config.getFilterChain().addLast("codec", new ProtocolCodecFilter(new TextLineCodecFactory(Charset.forName("UTF-8")) ));
    config.getFilterChain().addLast("to-message", new ToMessageIoFilter());

    config.getSessionConfig().setReuseAddress( true );
    config.getSessionConfig().setTcpNoDelay(true);
    acceptor.bind( new InetSocketAddress(PORT), new MinaServerHandler(new MinaConnectionFactory()), config );
}
```

Here is how I send out a sequence of messages:

```
public  void sendMessage(String msg) throws IOException {
    synchronized(session){
        writeLine("MSGHEAD");
        writeLine(msg);
        writeLine(".");
    }
}

private void writeLine(String line) {
    WriteFuture w=session.write(line);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If three threads are each in loops of `sendMessage()` then you would expect them to output the lines sometimes interleaved, sometimes not. Which is the behavior you describe.

I do see you've attempted to synchronize those threads in order to output full blocks of messages each. So what is probably going wrong is that each thread has it's own `session` object. Your threads must share the object on which they synchronize.

The simplest way to address this is to remove the synchronized statement and make `sendMessage()` a [synchronized method](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html). This might not be very speedy though.